It occurs to an error when deploying the ingress-nginx
I check the status of ingress-nginx.
[root@node1 yaml]# kubectl get pod -A
NAMESPACE       NAME                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-mznmk    0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          3m33s
kube-flannel    kube-flannel-ds-6bxtd             1/1     Running            1          22h
kube-flannel    kube-flannel-ds-nhqj5             1/1     Running            0          22h
kube-system     coredns-74ff55c5b-5wmkl           1/1     Running            1          22h
kube-system     coredns-74ff55c5b-f77tc           1/1     Running            1          22h
kube-system     etcd-master1                      1/1     Running            2          22h
kube-system     kube-apiserver-master1            1/1     Running            2          22h
kube-system     kube-controller-manager-master1   1/1     Running            2          22h
kube-system     kube-proxy-6dsrs                  1/1     Running            1          22h
kube-system     kube-proxy-9tt9d                  1/1     Running            2          22h
kube-system     kube-scheduler-master1            1/1     Running            2          22h

I analysis the error, but I can not solve it. You can watch this description.
[root@node1 yaml]# kubectl describe pod ingress-nginx-controller-mznmk -n ingress-nginx
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  6m42s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller-mznmk to master1
  Normal   Pulled     5m21s (x5 over 6m41s)  kubelet            Container image "nginx/nginx-ingress:1.3.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    5m21s (x5 over 6m41s)  kubelet            Created container controller
  Normal   Started    5m21s (x5 over 6m41s)  kubelet            Started container controller
  Warning  BackOff    99s (x27 over 6m39s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container

I have downloaded the image of ingress-nginx.
[root@master1 ingress-nginx]# docker images
REPOSITORY                                       TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
nginx/nginx-ingress                              1.3.0      e544e4c34937   6 years ago    134MB

What version of ingress-nginx I should download?

Back-off restarting may be for several reasons, check the logs for particular error or info for further debugging, meanwhile check this document.
